# Reading Bulk data from CSV and writring into another csv

Tags: java

I had one *csv file* of 1 cr lines of data. From this file I have to read data from *csv* and using first field I need do check conditions with in my db and from that Db took one key and append all prevoius data and write to another *csv*. Which ever I read from *CSV* I written code for this but it takes days of time to read and write for one 2 lakhs line of data. Here I am using single thread to do this all.
Sample code is I followed below steps:

> 1).reading data from CSF.
>   2).Read first field from csv and checking condition(in this i am
>   checking  5 conditions).
>   3).And written into CSV.

Comment: What is your question? Where is your sample code? Do you mean 100.000 with lakhs?

Comment: We can't advise on why your code is slow without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, reading the CSV into the database and then writing a statement to filter the data would be more efficient than reading the file line by line using the code.

You may refer the links below to know more about csv to database import if you use MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

http://support.modwest.com/content/6/253/en/how-do-i-import-delimited-data-into-mysql.html